# Не- с причастием

Tags: орфография

"Долги за уже полученные, но не оплаченные ценности" — верно ли написано слово «не оплаченные»?

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Писать надо слитно (нет зависимого слова, нет противопоставления). Если Вы добавите слово ЕЩЁ  - пишите раздельно. *Неоплаченные ценности  - еще не оплаченные ценности*